# How to debug a crashed Linux program by its glibc/malloc backtrace (no core available)?

Tags: c++, linux, glibc, coredump, debug-backtrace

I've a C++ application running on a remote server. I recently introduced a lot of new code. Fearing crashes, I had set `ulimit -c unlimited` and some time later I got a crash, with a coredump, which helped me debug a problem. For business reasons, the running binary has no debug symbols, but I do have the with-symbols binary on my PC, so debugging was a breeze.

Today the updated service crashed again, unfortunately it didn't produce a coredump this time (the old `core` file was still there, untouched, I guess it may be some kind of expected behaviour). The crash was within realloc() innards this time, so it presented me with this stack trace to stdout:

```
*** Error in `./MyApp': corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000003a04940 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f05ed2897e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7e6ed)[0x7f05ed2906ed]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x81cde)[0x7f05ed293cde]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x54)[0x7f05ed296184]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x358)[0x7f05ed296a18]
./MyApp[0x453f58]
./MyApp[0x454a42]
./MyApp[0x457cd6]
./MyApp[0x45eb19]
./MyApp[0x49cfd7]
./MyApp[0x49707b]
./MyApp[0x70734e]
...
a lot more lines
...
./MyApp[0x664c65]
./MyApp[0x73e7b2]
./MyApp[0x70d849]
./MyApp[0x783af4]
./MyApp[0x425da8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f05ed232830]
./MyApp[0x43a0c9]
======= Memory map: ========
...
< a huge table of memory mappings, ending with: >
Aborted (core dumped)
```

As stated above, the core file is not changed from the previous crash, so it cannot be used.

I was wondering whether I could use this stack trace to manually find out which function triggered the realloc() that wrecked everything. I tried `addr2line` using the addresses mentioned, but I feel it sends me to the wrong places, as they are completely irrelevant. Probably I should use the memory map in some way I don't understand and couldn't find out after some googling. Is there a guide for using this type of stack traces?

Comment: does this addresses aligned by memory randomizer? did you try search by call instructions in objdump?

Comment: Wow, yes, that solved it. I've run the with-symbols binary through objdump, the addresses from this stacktrace match up with the ones from objdump, the stack trace makes sense now. Many thanks! Feel free to turn your objdump suggestion into an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objdump` - one cool program from GNU toolchain, that can show you information about binary. linked libraries, memory alignments, function tables and much more.

Common use:
`objdump -T <file>`

There are some more tools, that can help you. like `nm` or `readelf` (for elf files).

`nm -g -C <file>`
`readelf -sW <file>`

Comment: As mentioned in comments, objdump decoded all instructions in my with-symbol binary, and searching the addresses from the realloc stack trace matched to the exact instructions I expected; for some reason `addr2line` was giving misleading results, probably because my binary is compiled with -O2.